# How to adjust the quartz scheduler timing?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz scheduler for scheduling a particular job. I am using both trigger types simple and cron. I have set the interval time as 4 minutes for testing purpose.

If the first run takes 2 minutes to execute then second run starts after 2 minutes the first run finishes. This should not happen. In this case interval time gets reduced to 2 minutes. This should not happen. The second job should start 4 minutes after the first job finishes. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should schedule the job once with 4 minutes delay, after job completes (use job listener to catch the moment), reschedule it again at the same 4 minutes interval.

Also, if it is not necessary to use the quartz, it could be enough to use `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`.